# To use WDK in VS2019, which Spectre-mitigated library should be installed

Tags: visual-studio-2019, wdk, spectre

When using WDK in VS2019, I get this build error:

> Error MSB8040: Spectre-mitigated libraries are required for this project

There are a lot of items in VS2019 setup that contains "spectre".

This https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk#wdk-for-windows-10-version-1903 says:

> For each architecture you intend to build drivers for, install the Spectre mitigated libraries thru Individual Components -> Compilers, build tools, and runtimes -> MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C+ x64/x86 Spectre-mitigated libs (v14.21).

This https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/746245/spectre-mitigated-libraries-are-required-for-this.html says

> I think you need to install the following components: MSVC V142 - VS
>   2019 C++ x64/x86 Spectre-mitigated libs (v14.xx) C++ ATL for latest
>   v142 build tools with Spectre-mitigations (x86 & x64) C++ MFC for
>   latest v142 build tools with Spectre-mitigations (x86 & x64)

Which to install?

Answer (score 2):

VS2019 toolset "WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0" (which you need to select to build driver projects) seems to use the highest version of C++ toolset that VS2019 supports.

For now the highest version is 14.23 so only need to install

```
MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 Spectre-mitigated libs (v14.23)
```

Comment: In my case I had to install the "MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 Spectre-mitigated libs (latest)" variant.